# Hibernate @SelectBeforeUpdate(false) not working if without a hibernate generated value of @Id

Tags: java, hibernate

I found that if the entity mapping without a hibernate generated primary key value, the `SelectBeforeUpdate(false)` will not working.

```
@Entity
@SelectBeforeUpdate(false)
class X {
    protected X(){}
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    UUID id;

    int x;
}
```

If comment out `@GeneratedValue`, assign id value in X ctor, the `@SelectBeforeUpdate(false)` will lose its functionality.

Due to hibernate will check a detached object is transient or not by `ForeignKeys.isTransient` in `org\hibernate\engine\internal\ForeignKeys.java` which finally call `IdentifierValue.isUnsaved` in `org\hibernate\engine\spi\IdentifierValue.java`. Without `@GeneratedValue`, hibernate use a static `UNDEFINED` instance of class `IdentifierValue` which `isUnsaved` method always return `null`. That will cause `ForeignKeys.isTransient` return `null` so that hibernate will build the snapshot at last which will trigger a selection SQL.

However, the problem is that `@GeneratedValue` split the object construction to 2 phase: first new it then pass it into session.save. I don't like this, is there a workaround to make `@SelectBeforeUpdate(false)` works without let hibernate generated the @Id value? I use UUID to be the pk so it is unnecessary let hibernate to do this.

I use hibernate 5

Comment: Not sure I follow. You would like to avoid autogenerated IDs, and still would like Hibernate to know, without checking the database first, if the entity is a new one or a detached one, is that right? How could it do that? Why do you want to avoid auto-generated IDs? They solve the problem: if the ID is null, then the entity is new, otherwise it's detached. And Hibernate has a UUID generator.

Comment: The checking is its internal procedure which the behavior can be changed. After read the code, the only way to alter the procedure is setting a self-defined Interceptor to SessionFactory which override isTransient method: for object of X, return false. But doing this require user only can call save or persist for transient object, call update for non-transient object. So neither add @GeneratedValue or set custom Interceptor is perfect way. I want to void auto-generated IDs because it is kind of burden of mind: not access id if it has not passed to session.save yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figure out this mechanism. For hibernate, the @Id field are processed in an uniformed procedure whatever the type is: if you want hibernate generate the id value for you, you must call session.save, even the id value can be determined at the stage of object construction.

This is problematic: if user use UUID to be the primary key, that means user want to determine the value ahead of communicating with database. For some complex logic, after the object A create, the object A need to do some additional things, after that, the object A need along with another object B in an transaction to commit to database. If the object A's id is null till database commit, it is very inconvenient due to object is not a complete object yet.

Hibernate use the uniform id generation procedure as an assumption which used to determine the object is transient or not. If `@GeneratedValue` is add, hibernate consider object is transient only if the id value is null(This is quite simple, if the id value is not null, then session.save must be called). If without a generator, hibernate can not know the fact, the only way to find out is select it out from database. So it have to omit the @SelectBeforeUpdate(false)

The only way to alter the procedure is self define a Interceptor which override the Interceptor.isTransient, however doing this require user implement the transient checking. If always return false in it, the save and update must be called precisely.